# Drag & Drop UI Issue in jquery,php

Tags: php, jquery, css, jquery-ui, user-interface

I am using the drag and drop jQuery script in my PHP project.

We can drag the table row and drop into the div. That is the process.

jQuery's function is working fine but have to drop the table row into the left corner of the `drop_div`, not full div accept the drop function.

I had applied background color for the drop_div for checking purpose, it is applied correctly.

Only the drop function is not working.

It treats `drop_div` width as if it is much lower.

What should I do?

I'll share my code if required.

Comment: Can you supply your HTML and jQuery Code? And possibly a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) showing the issue?

Comment: draggable table row and droppable div are generated dynamically. this is the link-         http://jsfiddle.net/PLZzy/

Comment: Using [this trimmed down version](http://jsfiddle.net/Nunners/EBV3C/1/) (Manually created table and removed the code from the `Dropped` function) the div allows you to "drop" the element anywhere on the red background. I can't replicate your problem.

Comment: hi Nunners, that is working in jsfiddle but not in live site. is any other issue ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/EBV3C/4/ - this is my coding structure. It is working fine in jsfiddle not live site. What is the issue ?

Comment: There must be something else in your site that changes the Div or that affects this code, try searching for this. I can't really help more than that.

Comment: hi Nunners, this is my code exactly,having the same problem in jsfiddle also.        http://jsfiddle.net/KJs43/

Comment: The problem is the width of the element, the 7% is not big enough, also when dropping an element on another, the "center point" of the draggable element must be within the droppable element. You can see this by looking here : http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#revert, if you drag the second element over the droppable box but keep the center point outside the box, it will be reverted.

Comment: oh ok thank you Nanners. Great help. I have increased the width and make sort out some design issues then it is working fine. Thank you lot..